# Custom UIButton drawing - stays depressed after touchesEnded

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uibutton, core-graphics

I've made a custom zero-image, Core Graphics drawn UIButton based on [Ray Wenderlich's Tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2134/core-graphics-101-glossy-buttons) (the only modifications are to CoolButton's `drawRect:` method, altered drawing code), and it works great most of the time. However, sometimes when I click it for a short period of time, it stays in a depressed state and doesn't return to normal.

From here, the only way to get it back to a normal state is via a long press. Simply clicking means it stays depressed.

Another thing to note is that I've hooked Touch Up Inside up to a chain of a few long methods - I don't think it would take more than 0.1 seconds to complete. I've even used `dispatch_async` in the `@selector` that is hooked up to Touch Up Inside, so there shouldn't be a delay in the UI updating, I think.

---

I've put an `NSLog` in the `drawRect:` which fires 3 times per button press usually, and it varies what `UIControlState` the button is in for each press:

- For some short presses, it goes Highlighted, Highlighted, Normal
- for longer presses, it's Highlighted, Normal, Normal

However, for very short presses, it only fires twice, Highlighted -> Highlighted.

When it's a long press to get it back to Normal, it goes H, N, N.

---

This has been puzzling me for a while, and I haven't been able to work out why short presses only fire `drawRect:` twice, or why `touchesEnded:` doesn't seem to call `drawRect:`. Perhaps `touchesEnded:` isn't firing?

I really hope someone can help.

Comment: Does it work when you do not use GCD?

Comment: Can't comment as to exactly why it's not happening, but it's probably not a great idea to redraw every time from scratch for a touchup/touchdown. Why not generate a UIImage, cache it and use that? Much better from a performance standpoint, as would just using images in the first place.

Comment: A depressed button :)) This should be made a meme :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you *really* want to generate the button images at runtime, generate them when the button is loaded. Then add them for different states using

```
[button setImage:btnImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

You can always turn a view into an image using the following: http://pastie.org/244916

Really though, I'd recommend just making images beforehand. If you don't want to get photoshop, there's plenty of alternatives. The upcoming [pixelmator](http://www.pixelmator.com/sneak-preview/) update looks pretty suave, ands it's ridiculously cheap!

Comment: Thanks for that. I've been waiting out on Pixelmator 2, I agree, looks awesome. I'll try that, see how it goes.

Comment: Do you reckon it's possible to only draw at runtime if a previously stored generated image can't be found? That way, I could set a `BOOL` when I want it to generate each time, but for when I'm finished making changes to the drawing code, I could set it back and have it look for the image each time. If that makes sense :)

Comment: Certainly. To check if an image can be found, use the following:

Comment: NSString * appPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]; NSString * file = [appPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"filename.png"];
BOOL fileExists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:file];

Comment: But can you save a UIImage to your bundle's resourcePath?

Comment: Oooh I see what you're saying now! Yes great idea, replace "resourcePath" with "documentsPath" I think (I can't remember off the top of my head). There should be tutorials aplenty online for how to save/read/check if files exist in the documents directory :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, well, that was easy. 0.15 second delay works, 0.1 doesn't.

Comment: This isn't really a good solution. Time is dependent on processor speed etc - so this 'fix' will only work in certain cases. If I was you, I'd find a solution that doesn't have anything to do with waiting a certain amount of time :)

Answer (score 0):

As other said, you can simply generate an image and use that as background (if the image is static). No need photoshop, you may simply generate your image once and then take a snapshot, then cut the image out (with Anteprima) and save it as a png file :)

However, since you said the button is connected to some long methods, this may be why the button stay pressed: if you are not calling those methods in background, then the button will stay pressed since all the task are ended. Try (for a test) to connect the button with a single simple method (say `NSLog` something) and check if it stay pressed. If not, I suggest to detach your methods in background.

Answer (score 0):

I too ran into a similar problem with a UIButton appearing to stick one state when I customize the drawRect method. My hunch is that the state of the button is changing more than once before drawRect is called. So I just added a custom property that would only be set by methods called during touchDown and touchUpInside events. I had to dispatch threads to do this because of other operations that were holding up the main thread, causing a delay in the redrawHighlighted method.

It may be a little messy, but here's what worked for me:

```
// CustomButton.h
@interface CustomButton : UIButton
@property (atomic) BOOL drawHighlighted;    

// CustomButton.m
@implementation CustomButton
@synthesize drawHighlighted = _drawHighlighted;

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    if ((self = [super initWithFrame:frame]))
    {
        _drawHighlighted = NO;

        [self addTarget:self action:@selector(redrawHighlighted) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
        [self addTarget:self action:@selector(redrawNormal) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [self addTarget:self action:@selector(redrawNormal) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDragExit];  
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)frame
{
    // draw button here
}

- (void)redrawNormal
{
    [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(redrawRectForNormal) toTarget:self withObject:nil];
}

- (void)redrawHighlighted
{
    [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(redrawRectForHighlighted) toTarget:self withObject:nil];
}

- (void)redrawRectForNormal
{
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    _drawHighlighted = NO;  
    [self setNeedsDisplay];

    [pool release];
}

- (void)redrawRectForHighlighted
{
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    _drawHighlighted = YES; 
    [self setNeedsDisplay];

    [pool release];
}
```

Comment: I'm curious as to why this was down-voted without explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Another cheap but effective alternative I've found is to create a drawRect: that doesn't do any highlighting, and simply alter the button subclass's alpha property when the user interacts with the button.

For example:

```
- (BOOL)beginTrackingWithTouch:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    self.alpha = 0.3f;
    return [super beginTrackingWithTouch:touch withEvent:event];
}

- (void)endTrackingWithTouch:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    self.alpha = 1.0f;
    [super endTrackingWithTouch:touch withEvent:event];
}

- (void)cancelTrackingWithEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    self.alpha = 0.3f;
    [super cancelTrackingWithEvent:event];
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    // Your drawing code here sans highlighting
}
```